# Accessing a variable set in one component file in another file React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, jsx

I am quite new to react and am trying to create a sports fixture application where when you click on one of the fixtures in the list it takes you to a new page with more things you can do for that fixture.

On my home page I render the list of popular fixtures which I have set in a JSON called popular.json. I have this coded so if I add or remove a fixture from [popular.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9CKx.png) then this will automatically be rendered by having my component set up as below

```
import fixtures from './variables/popular.json'  

export const setFixture = (id, home, homeLogo, away, awayLogo, date, time, venue) => {
  const match = { id: id, teamA: home, teamALogo: homeLogo, teamB: away, teamBLogo: awayLogo, date: date, time: time, stadium: venue } 
}

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <div >
      <div className="max-w-4xl mx-auto px-4 py-1 sm:px-6 sm:pt-20 sm:pb-24 lg:max-w-7xl lg:pt-10 lg:px-8">
        <h2 className="text-4xl font-bold text-white tracking-tight">
          Popular
        </h2>
        <ul
          time="list"
          className="grid grid-cols-1 py-10 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3"
        >

          {fixtures.map((fixture) => (
            <li key={fixture.id} className="col-span-1 rounded-lg bg-white bg-opacity-70 hover:bg-gray-100 shadow">
              <a href="/game" onClick={setFixture(fixture.home,fixture.homeLogo,fixture.away,fixture.awayLogo,fixture.date,fixture.time,fixture.venue)}>
                <div>
                  <div className="-mt-px flex">
                    <div className="flex w-0 flex-1">
                      <div className="mx-auto py-5 flex-shrink-0 flex justify-center">

                        <img
                          className="h-16 w-16"
                          src={fixture.homeLogo}
                          alt="Logo"
                        />

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-1"></div>
                    <div className="-ml-px flex w-0 flex-1">
                      <div className="mx-auto py-5 flex-shrink-0 flex items-center justify-center">
                        <img
                          className="h-16 w-16"
                          src={fixture.awayLogo}
                          alt="Logo"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="-mt-px items-center flex">
                    <div className="flex w-0 flex-1">
                      <div className="relative -mr-px inline-flex w-0 flex-1 items-center justify-center rounded-bl-lg border border-transparent py-4 text-3xl font-bold text-gray-600 hover:text-purple-600">
                        <span className="justify-center">{fixture.home}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex w-1">
                      <div className="justify-center flex w-0 flex-1">
                        <span className="text-4xl font-bold text-center text-gray-600 hover:text-purple-600 tracking-tight">
                          V
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="-ml-px flex w-0 flex-1">
                      <div className="relative inline-flex w-0 flex-1 items-center justify-center rounded-br-lg border border-transparent py-4 text-3xl font-bold text-gray-600 hover:text-purple-600">
                        <span className="justify-center">{fixture.away}</span>
                      ...
```

and so on and it looks like this [render of fixtures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Ti3.jpg)

When you click on one of these games it redirects to the /game page where I want to build add more stuff you can see about each game.

I want to know which game has been selected by the setFixture function which is called onClick of one of the games, and then I want to pass in the match variable to my new component (which is in a different .jsx file) so that I can render the game that has been selected on the new page.

I have tried to import the match variable from this file and the setFixture function in the new component file but cannot set my variables for the teams, date, venue etc. from this import and am just seeing many errors.

Can anyone help me with how this can be done? Recognizing which game has been selected and loading this into another file?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to problems in React is to make use of Components. A component represents an object, and is provided a set of properties to allow that instance of the object to be represented.
So, even before going to your "next page" think about the Components that you could have on this "page" - each of the Fixtures you are representing can be a Component that takes properties that will help render the teams in that match. This will then lead to less repetition in each of your components - the Example() component will now render (for example) 6 Fixture() components.

Also, React is usually a Single Page Application. Whilst you're getting your basic application working you don't need to consider Routing just yet. Also, pages aren't "loaded"; components are re-rendered when Component properties ("props" for short) are updated. So, in the same page above you could have a Game() component that initially doesn't have any team props sent to it and behaves by not rendering until it has teams set.
You could use something like https://stackblitz.com/ to showcase what you have now, and it'd be easier to show how your code can be simplified.